# How to design CMOS bridge rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, cmos, bridge, energy-harvesting

I designed the bridge rectifier circuit.
I wnat to make a full-wave rectification. so, I made a CMOS circuit.
I refered to other papers. Figure2.
"An ultra-low-voltage self-powered energy harvesting rectifier with digital switch control"
[Link](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/elex/12/3/12_12.20140921/_pdf):

[image]

I think this circuit is full-wave rectification. But the result is a half-wave rectifier circuit. Is the result of this graph correct?[image]
[image]

And my theme is Energy Harvesting. So input in mV units. I had input 0.3V but Simulations output is 1V. Why does this result?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: can you add the link in the comment. any one will add it to the question for you.

Comment: https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/elex/12/3/12_12.20140921/_article

Comment: Have you tried a higher input voltage?

Comment: I tried 3V input. But still operation 1V input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ground the voltage source to the same ground as the output.  You should remove the bottom ground and you will also need a load resistance.

Here is a schematic and simulation of a circuit that functions as a full wave bridge rectifier.  This was done in LTSpice.

[image: Full Wave Rectifier]

[image: Simulation output]

Comment: I removed 1 gnd. Also, I added 10Kohm load resistance. But it is still a half-wave rectifier circuit.

Comment: Please update the schematic and probe the other side of  the AC source.

Comment: I updated the picture as you wish. And my theme is Energy Harvesting. So input in mV units.

Comment: You still have the unwanted ground in your schematic and you haven't probed both sides of the AC source. Your Virtuoso schematic does not match the simplified one.

Comment: I modified the circuit.

Comment: In my opinion, this circuit is full wave rectification. right?

Comment: Yes - it looks like it should work however the AC source MUST be floating.  Neither of its terminals can connect to ground.  I'm not convinced you have the Virtuoso schematic (or whatever you created the schematic in) has been modified correctly.  The simplified circuit and the detailed one are NOT the same.

Comment: Thank you. I will look for other circuits and simulate them.

Comment: Your simplified circuit should work.  I have added a circuit and simulation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Which paper did you refer to the circuit you uploaded? I also have to add Somoothing Circuit and DC-DC convter. I have tried various experiments and I will ask again.

Comment: I didn't refer to any paper - this is the same circuit as you have.  I left off the MP3 and MN3 as they are not part of the rectification process.